# Does $(v - v_0) \perp v_0 \implies \|v_0\| \leq \|v\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

Sort of stuck on this fine point for a while now:

Suppose we have some vector space $V$ and some $v_0, v \in V$, such that $(v - v_0) \perp v_0$

Does $(v - v_0) \perp v_0 \implies \|v_0\| \leq \|v\|$ hold?

Comment: What is $\lVert v_0 + (v-v_0)\rVert^2$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\|v\|^2 = \|v-v_o + v_o\|^2 \leq \|v-v_o\|^2 + \|v_o\|^2$. At this point how can you get rid of $|v-v_o\|^2$ at the same time showing that the reverse inequality is true?

Comment: Use $(v-v_0) \perp v_0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's what I don't get :( how we can use something involving inner product of two non-identical vectors to prove something from norm which only take one vector. So $(v - v_o) \perp v_o \Rightarrow \langle v -v_o, v_o \rangle = 0$ , then $\langle v -v_o, v_o \rangle = \langle v, v_o \rangle - \langle v_o, v_o \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow \langle v, v_o \rangle = \|v_o\|^2$ Thats as far as I got

Comment: Generally, you have $\lVert x + y\rVert^2 =\,?$

Comment: What you got ($\langle v,v_0\rangle=\|v_0\|^2$) is useful if you apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel It works fine, but how does that help proving$ ∥v∥^2=∥v−v_o+v_o∥^2≤∥v−v_o∥^2+∥v_o∥^2  \Rightarrow \|v\| \geq \|v_o\|$

Comment: $\|v_0\|^2=\langle v,v_o\rangle\leq\|v\|\|v_o\|\implies\|v_o\|\leq\|v\|$ (if $v_o\neq 0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this question out

Suppose $v-v_o \perp v_o$

Then $\|v\|^2 = \|(v - v_o) + v_o \|^2 = \|v-v_o\|^2 + \|v_o\|^2$

Note that in this case we have equality, this is a special case of the triangle inequality that all norms have to satisfy. This is only possible since $v-v_o \perp v_o$. Using equivalence between $\|\cdot\|^2$ and $<\cdot, \cdot>$ this can be shown. Actually this is called the pythagoras theorem but generalized to higher dimensional vectors.

Therefore, since all norms are positive (or 0), $\|v-v_o\|^2 \geq 0$, hence $\|v\|^2 \geq \|v_o\|^2$ and the conclusion follows by taking square root of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it holds based on Pythagoras. The three vectors must create a right angle triangle in which $v$ is the hypotenuse.